# How to safely embed query params in a javascript response from node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xss, owasp

There are libraries out there, like the [OWASP java encoder](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder), that make it relatively easy to embed untrusted content in any context. I'm looking for something that can do this in a JavaScript block context, and I need it to work in Node.js.

Specifically, I'm trying to write an Express route that will return some dynamic JavaScript. The use case is something like:

```html
<script src="/my-custom-route?config1=A&config2=B"></script>
```

Here's a very wrong, bad, naive implementation to hopefully help paint the picture of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```js
let scriptCache = null;
server.get(
    '/my-custom-route',
    async (req, res) => {
        const config1 = req.query && req.query.config1 ? req.query.config1 : '';
        const config2 = req.query && req.query.config2 ? req.query.config2 : '';

        if (scriptCache === null) {
            scriptCache = await fs.readFile('./data/some-customizable-script.txt', 'utf-8');
        }

        //THIS IS A TERRIBLE BAD IDEA DONT DO THIS
        const embedScript = scriptCache
            .replace(/\$\{config1\}/g, encodeURIComponent(config1))
            .replace(/\$\{config2\}/g, encodeURIComponent(config2));

        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
        return res.status(200).send(embedScript);
    }
);
```

For the purposes of this illustration, let's say that the content of `some-customizable-script.txt` is this:

```js
alert('${config1}');
```

It's easy to see how to XSS this setup. This is where I would usually reach for `encode.forJavascript()`, but I can't find a library that implements this output context. I've found two that seem like they are reasonably sophisticated ([XSS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss) and [XSS-Filters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss-filters)), but as far as I can tell both are targeting outputting HTML.

Is there a trusted library for accomplishing this in node.js?

Comment: Why are you trying to inject a script from the server? Why can't a static JS file (maybe even uploaded to CDN) work?

Comment: The typical approach to this issue, as far as OWASP is concerned, I believe would be to have a whitelist mapping.  Don't just accept in any inputs for config1 or config2.  You should whitelist which ones they have access to, assign identifiers to them, and have the frontend pass in those identifiers.  Then your backend looks up in the whitelist to see which backend file the identifier goes to and returns the matching one.  If it doesn't match anything, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @MukundGoel the script will be used to embed an iframe in the page. Kind of like how you can do a youtube embed, but instead of a video you're creating an iframe. Just like the youtube embed, we need to be able to pass in some parameters to make the script do the right thing (e.g. load the right contents into the iframe)

Comment: @Taplar while a direct whitelist won't be practical (user-generated content), I might be able to do something inspired by that -- I would have to validate the config variable over an API request, but I can cache that result. That should work, thanks.

Comment: After reading your comment about your intentions.  I would have to agree with @MukundGoel in this case it would be better to just give them the iframe with a url that points to an endpoint that will handle the configuration based on a token.